# I want to fetch specific data from JSON file and add it to another JSON file/variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so i want to fetch data from this api:
http://csgobackpack.net/api/GetItemsList/v2/
Its large database so i want to get only a few information for every item, like 7days price. And than save it in my file. But when i use empty obect the very first object in variable is 
"[object][object]"

```
Request.get("http://csgobackpack.net/api/GetItemsList/v2/", {
    json: true
}, (error, response, body) => { 
      csgo = new Object();
      if(body['success']) {
       for(let key in body.items_list)
          csgo+=("\"" + body.items_list[key].name + "\" :{" 
"\"icon\"" + ":" + "\"" + body.items_list[key].icon_url + "\","+
"\"exterior\"" + ":" + "\"" + body.items_list[key].exterior + "\"}"

}
```

Comment: is body or body.items_list text in JSON format? You may need to call JSON.parse() on something

Comment: There is essentially *never* a need to compose JSON manually like that. Also, you declared `csgo` as `Object`, then try to add text to it.

Comment: @ChrisG ok so if i should do it manually like that, than what can i do?

Comment: @TKoL I think so, because when i wanted to pare it, there was an error

Comment: No you don't. `body` is fully parsed into an Object already.

Comment: @ChrisG i have tried, i wrote body = JSON.parse(body); but i have an error:
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @Sebqu But I just told you that it's already parsed... `body` is fine as it is. Where your code goes wrong is the `csgo+=` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is still the source of much confusion unfortunately. JSON is *text*. Text that happens to be using a syntax that is very similar to how Objects are defined in JavaScript.
The code you have uses `json: true`, and `Request.get` consequently parses the reply into an Object for you. This becomes clear when you use `if (body['success'])`, since if the API response were a string still, there wouldn't be a `success` property.

Which means JSON is completely out of the picture now, we're only dealing with JavaScript objects. We can access their properties using dot or brackets notation, and construct new ones.

Here's code that will grab the first 5 items and log the result:

```
const Request = require("request");

Request.get("http://csgobackpack.net/api/GetItemsList/v2/", { json: true }, (error, response, body) => {
    // body contains the JSON reply already parsed into a JS Object
    csgo = new Object();
    if (body['success']) {
        var limit = 5;
        for (let key in body.items_list) {
            // shorter way to grab multiple properties
            const { icon_url, exterior } = body.items_list[key];
            // add child to csgo
            csgo[key] = { icon: icon_url, exterior }; // OR: exterior: exterior
            if (--limit === 0) break;
        }
        console.log(csgo);
    }
});
```

The key part is

```
csgo[key] = { icon: icon_url, exterior };
```

A new property is added to the object and set to the specified object literal.

Comment: Thank you so much!